# How to accept only one active session in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL table named `sessions` which has `id, name, startDate, endDate, status`, and the `status` column has a default value of 'active' after the session is completed the status should be changed to 'closed'.

How can I check if the existing session is 'active' and notify if there is any when creating the session so I can't have multiple 'active' sessions?

I have this stored procedure to create session table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure createSession(IN  name VARCHAR(100), startDate DATE , endDate DATE) 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO academicYear (  name , startDate , endDate ) VALUES (  name , startDate , endDate );
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

*NB: `status` column has default value : 'active'

**academicYear records:**

[image: here]

Comment: We would help to see some code to would help us out answering.

Comment: ok cool ll update the question asap

Comment: *"my question is how to check if the existing session is 'active' and notify if there is any so I can't have multiple 'active' sessions ?"*  You mean per application user?

Comment: to be consise the table session is the academic year of school , its not the session that is related to user

Comment: Is this a complete example? If so, can you give an example of the data in `academicYear`  (about 3 records will do)?

Comment: @Luuk yes i can give , check the question again

Comment: as you can see i have one active and one closed records,  what i want is that my status column to accept multiple ''closed status values , but there should be only one active value in the colum hope its clear

Comment: I think the active year should be based on the current date? (The example with 2 years with same startDate and endDate might be wrong, or not correct?)  Like: `SELECT if FROM  academicYear WHERE now() BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;`.  Positive site effect: there is no need to change `status` at the end of the year.

Comment: @Luuk yes thats correct name , startDate , endDate should be unique , if thats the case how should we change the status to 'closed' when the endDate reaches ?

Answer (score 0):

To know the status of an `academicYear`, you could do:

```sql
SELECT
   Name,
   startDate,
   endDate,
   CASE WHEN now() BETWEEN startDate AND endDate 'Active' ELSE 'Closed' END  as status
FROM 
   academicYear;
```